# Change postgresql data directory location

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Currenly my postgresql service running with

```
/usr/local/psql/bin/postmaster -d /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Due to insufficient disk space (data directory having 10GB of data), I planned to do the following steps:

Step1:

```
service postgresql stop
```

Step2:

```
mkdir -p /newdisk/newdata
chown postgres:postgres /newdisk/newdata
```

Step 3:

Change PGDATA path in /etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql file

From

```
PGDATA=/usr/local/pgsql/data
```

To

```
PGDATA=/newdisk/newdata
```

Step 4:

```
initdb -D /newdisk/newdata
service postgresql start
```

If I do above steps, expecting 10GB data will be moved to /newdisk/newdata path and henceforth, new transactions will be stored in /newdisk/newdata path.

This approach is fine to proceed? or do I need to consider anything else?

(Using Postgresql 9.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Your way, also EXPORT PGDATA=/newdisk/newdata

but also You can move all files to the new disk, and mount this disk to old PGDATA path (if all disk for PGSQL only)

```
Edit your /etc/fstab:
/dev/disk_name    /usr/local/psql/data    auto   defaults    1   2
```

Comment: thanks for the replay. I will try yours. can I move the /usr/local/psql/data to /data (will do the startup parameter change accordingly in /etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql). Will it impact anything?